# The translations doesn't work when I send an email in zf2

Tags: php, email, zend-framework2, zend-translate

I'm using the mailing library from zend framework 2, and also I'm using the translator functionality. But the translations only work inside the template .phtml, and not work in the service function for send the email, for example in translating the subject of the email. This is my code inside my service function to send an email:

```
$mailFactory = $this->getDependency('mail');
$viewModel = new ViewModel(array(
    'variable' => $x
));
$viewModel->setTemplate('template.phtml');
$message = $mailFactory->prepareMessage($viewModel);
$message->getHeaders()
    ->addHeaderLine('MIME-Version', '1.0')
    ->addHeaderLine('Content-type', 'text/html; charset=UTF-8');
$message->setSubject($this->translate('Recover your password'));
$message->setEncoding("UTF-8");
$message->addTo($email, $fullname);
$transport = $mailFactory->getTransport();

return $transport->send($message);
```

The function `$this->translate('...')` calls to a class that call this code: `return $this->translator->translate($text)`, this works well in all my application, but only works wrong when I send any email (with an exception of the `template.phtml`, inside this file the translator works well). All my mails received, have the subject in english (not translated) and the content in spanish (translated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the translator to the service to use it.

So in your module.config.php under the `service_manager` key you can do it with a factory or an initializer.

Factory:

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'YourNamespace\YourMailService' => function ($serviceManager) {
            $mailService = new YourNamespace\YourMailService();
            $mailService->setTranslator($serviceManager->get('translator'));
            return $mailService;
        },
    )
),
```

You need the method `setTranslator` in your service class!

Inititalizer:

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'initializers' => array(
        function ($instance, $sm)
        {
            if ($instance instanceof \YourNamespace\TranslatorAwareInterface) {
                $instance->setTranslator($sm->get('translator'));
            }
        }
    ),
),
```

With an initializer you need the interface `TranslatorAwareInterface`:

```
namespace YourNamespace;

use Zend\Mvc\I18n\Translator;

interface TranslatorAwareInterface
{
    public function setTranslator(Translator $translator);
}
```

And your service need to implement that interface:

```
class YourMailService implements TranslatorAwareInterface
{
    protected $translator;

    public function setTranslator(Translator $translator)
    {
        $this->translator = $translator;
    }
}
```

In both cases you can use the translator like:

```
$message->setSubject($this->translator->translate('Recover your password'));
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that and I'll give you a feedback.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I see that I can custom my mail service and setting the translator instance to the service in the initializers of the service manager. Now I found the solution for my case. In the service where I have the code to send the email, I only got the translator object $translator = $this->getDependency('translator'); and in the ServiceFactory I added the dependency for translator with $serviceLocator->get('translator'). Now I can translate the text in my service with $translator->translate('text').